# Cannot find module at AVA test

Tags: reactjs, testing, ava

I am trying to setup the AVA at my react project.

So I added this code into my package.json:

```
 "ava": {
    "babel": "inherit",
    "register": [
      "babel-register",
      "./test/helpers/browser-env.js",
      "ignore-styles"
    ]
  }

  "scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "ava \"app/**/*.test.js\" --verbose"
   }
```

And made the Header.test.js:

```
import test from 'ava';

import React from 'react';
import { renderJSX } from 'jsx-test-helpers';

import Header from './Header';

test('it renders', (t) => {
  const wrapper = renderJSX(<Header attendant={null} />);
  t.true(wrapper);
});
```

When I run the test I got this error:

> Error: Cannot find module './Header'

The picture from my folder structure:

[image: My folder structure]

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to import `./Header.jsx`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gotting the error 'Unexpected token import' now. Can you help me?

Comment: Make sure your Babel config includes the https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs plugin.